# Reference a function from codebehind inside Repeater to get a different item URL if necessary

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sitecore, sitecore7.2

I am working on updating the code for navigation on a site so that it can include a check for whether a certain field is selected or not in the template. The navigation is built out using repeaters and features linq style coding. The navigation is 3 levels deep, and any page could have a checkbox field selected that is labeled, "Redirect to First Child Item." If this field is checked, then I'd like to run this function:

```
private string GetURL(ChaNavItem item)
{
    string returnedURL = string.Empty;

    // Check to see whether or nor a redirect to the first child is needed
    if (item.RedirectToFirstChild == true)
    {
        Item urlItem = db.Items[item.SitecoreID.ToString()];
        if (urlItem.HasChildren)
        {
            returnedURL = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(urlItem.Children[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            returnedURL = item.URL;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        returnedURL = item.URL;
    }

    return returnedURL;
}
```

That function takes the Sitecore item and checks which URL to return. I was hoping that maybe I could somehow make use of this function in the repeater where I get set the link. Currently, I am just getting the current link of the item, and nothing else:

```
<a href="<%# Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Item) %>" runat="server" class="child"><%# Item.Fields["Menu Title"].Value %>
```

It seems like it should be simple, but it's not (at least not to me). Here is the code behind for reference where the repeater data is setup:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    currentItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
    CurrentMenuTitle.Text = currentItem.Fields["Menu Title"].Value;
    var db = Sitecore.Context.Database;
    homePageItem = db.Items[homePageId];


    var TopLevelItems = currentItem.Children.Where(c => c.Fields["Hide From Menus"].Value != "1" && c.Fields["Hidden Page"].Value != "1");
    if (currentItem.TemplateID.ToString() != topLevelNavTemplateID)
    {
        var ancestors = currentItem.Axes.GetAncestors().ToList<Item>();
        foreach (Item ancestor in ancestors)
        {
            if (ancestor.TemplateID.ToString() == topLevelNavTemplateID)
            {
                TopLevelItems = ancestor.Children.Where(c => c.Fields["Hide From Menus"].Value != "1" && c.Fields["Hidden Page"].Value != "1");
            }
        }
    }
    SideNavRepeater.DataSource = TopLevelItems;
    SideNavRepeater.DataBind();

}

protected void SideNav_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var secondTierItem = e.Item.DataItem as Item;
    Repeater SiteNavSndLevelRepeater = e.Item.FindControl("SiteNavSndLevelRepeater") as Repeater;
    var thirdTierNavItems = secondTierItem.Children
       .Where(c => c.Fields["Hide From Menus"].Value != "1" && c.Fields["Hidden Page"].Value != "1");

    var arrowContainer = e.Item.FindControl("RightArrowContainer") as Panel;
    var indentationContainer = e.Item.FindControl("IndentedItemContainer") as Panel;

    if (thirdTierNavItems.Count() == 0)
    {
        arrowContainer.Visible = false;
        indentationContainer.Visible = true;
    }

    SiteNavSndLevelRepeater.DataSource = thirdTierNavItems;
    SiteNavSndLevelRepeater.DataBind();

}

protected void SiteNavSndLevel_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

    var secondTierItem = e.Item.DataItem as Item;
    Repeater SiteNavThirdLevelRepeater = e.Item.FindControl("SiteNavThirdLevelRepeater") as Repeater;
    var fourthTierNavItems = secondTierItem.Children
       .Where(c => c.Fields["Hide From Menus"].Value != "1" && c.Fields["Hidden Page"].Value != "1" && c.TemplateID.ToString() != "{5525F19B-B6E9-468E-934B-C4420C50B841}")
       .ToList();

    SiteNavThirdLevelRepeater.DataSource = fourthTierNavItems;
    SiteNavThirdLevelRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the method like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%# GetURL(Eval("myValue").ToString()) %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

And in code behind. Make sure the method is `public`

```
public string GetURL(string input)
{
    return "It works!";
}
```

Or if the method is not on the .cs of the page itself, but in another class, you need to provide the full namespace.

```
<%# Project1.Class.GetURL(Eval("myValue").ToString()) %>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response...this seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks!